# Реестр и параметры Java

Tags: java, реестр

Ребят, подскажите, где в реестре лежат значения Java ? Например, выделенная в данный момент память для Jav'ы..или любой другой путь, где лежит конфиг с данной информацией.

Comment: Для какой именно Java? Если разговор о производных от OpenJDK, то нигде не лежит, умолчания или вычисляющие их алгоритмы захардкожены в бинарник виртуальной машины. Посмотреть их можно, передав пару ключей - `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Тогда другой вопрос..могу ли я как то через C# задать -xmxNm ? (Кроме вызова консоли и передачи в нее аргументов (если так можно, конечно ))

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы запускаете JVM из C#. Если это запуск процесса java, то проще и разумнее всего передать значение ключом.